# PySpark DataFrame split struct array column

Tags: dataframe, pyspark

Suppose I have this column sorted, I want to split it into two columns, where the first column contains only every first element. and second column contains every second elements. Is this possible?

e.g. if I have `[[1,11], [2,22], [3,33]]`, then I want to split it into `[1,2,3]` and `[11,22,33]`

I looked up in column api but couldn't find anything.
Its not really a struct, I converted list tuple to DF. So something like this does work I think: `withColumn("x_values",col("sorted.x"))`.

I was able to do this by converting into RDD and map twice. But is there a faster way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

If you have limited number of columns then you can hard code for each like :

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df = spark.createDataFrame(data=[([1,11],), ([2,22],), ([3,33],)], schema=["c"])

df = df \
  .withColumn("c1", F.element_at("c", 1)) \
  .withColumn("c2", F.element_at("c", 2))

[Out]:
+-------+---+---+
|c      |c1 |c2 |
+-------+---+---+
|[1, 11]|1  |11 |
|[2, 22]|2  |22 |
|[3, 33]|3  |33 |
+-------+---+---+
```

If you want to generalise it, then select length of any column with good data, then use it to iterate over columns:

```py
col_len = len(df.limit(1).select("c").collect()[0]["c"])
for i in range(1, col_len + 1):
  df = df.withColumn(f"c{i}", F.element_at("c", i))
```

Comment: Did this solve your issue?